# understand the pointer pointer in c++ to get the function call

Tags: c++, pointers

I am little confused about the pointer statement in the following code.
The purpose of the pointer is to access the virtual function from virtual table.here is link of the article.
http://kaisar-haque.blogspot.com/2008/07/c-accessing-virtual-table.html

```
1 #include <iostream>
  2
  3 using namespace std;
  4
  5 //a simple class
  6 class X
  7 {
  8 public:
  9  //fn is a simple virtual function
 10  virtual void fn()
 11  {
 12   cout << "n = " << n << endl;
 13  }
 14
 15  //a member variable
 16  int n;
 17 };
 18
 19 int main()
 20 {
 21  //create an object (obj) of class X
 22  X *obj = new X();
 23  obj->n = 10;
 24
 25  //get the virtual table pointer of object obj
 26  int* vptr =  *(int**)obj;
 27
 28  // we shall call the function fn, but first the following assembly code
 29  //  is required to make obj as 'this' pointer as we shall call
 30  //  function fn() directly from the virtual table
 31  __asm
 32  {
 33   mov ecx, obj
 34  }
 35
 36  //function fn is the first entry of the virtual table, so it's vptr[0]
 37  ( (void (*)()) vptr[0] )();
 38
 39  //the above is the same as the following
 40  //obj->fn();
 41
 42  return 0;
 43 }
 44
```

so, i want to know the how to understand the line number 26.

Comment: Don't do hackery like this. It's way outside of what is well-defined in C++, and not necessary.

Comment: This code is undefined behavior. It may work mostly by chance with a specific version of a specific compiler on a specific operating system, but there's _never_ a reason to do this.

Comment: `*(int**)obj;` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: That being said, what about the long explanation in the linked article is not clear? We don't want to repeat the whole explanation only to _then_ find out what part you didn't get.

Comment: That article is talking about implementation details as if they were facts of c++. This isn't how c++ works. *Even if* you are on an implementation where what it assumes is true, it uses undefined behavior and might stop working at any time. It doesn't even specify how it was built or with what compiler versions, so you can't even semi-reliably use what it describes. There's hardly anything useful to learn from it. Line 26 is undefined behavior and there is nothing to understand from it other than to not do that.

Comment: yeah, i know it may have undefined behavior and out side the scope of c++. I just want to understand the line number 26..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is trying to do a hack base on some *possible* implementation of a virtual functionality in c++. The implementation of the vtable is not defined in the standard and its could be different with different compilers. It could be a subject to optimization as well.

The article is 10 years old and assumes a particular vtable implementation which was kind of common before those days:

1. first hidden pointer in the object (at object starting address) points to a array of functions.
2. the array of functions represents all virtual functions in the class. 
      Only compiler knows in which order they are put in the array. Declaration order was used usually.

Assuming the above implementation, address of 'obj' is really an address of the pointer to the virtual table. The example uses assumes that the function pointers can be represented as `int`s. It is simply not true for 64-bit OS and many others.  And `int *vptr` is a pointer to this array. So, *obj* points to a pointer to an array of int's `(int**)`. Consequently,  `*(int**)obj` is the pointer to the array itself.

The example then does another unsafe conversion from the vptr[0] (which is 'int') to a pointer to the function.

So, as a result you have a series of undefined or unsafe behaviors which could work for a particular implementation of a particular version of a particular compiler (probably 10 years old, same as the article).

DO NOT USE IT!!!